# MongoDB: How To use $group aggregation to get all data using similar field?

Tags: mongodb, mgo

I am trying to perform a query using golang mgo to effectively get similar  values from a join.
My structure is like this:

```
 result: [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "booking_id" : 96,
        "provider_id" : 20,
        "time" : NumberLong(1541158790),
        "arrival_time" : NumberLong(1541158863)
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "booking_id" : 96,
        "provider_id" : 20,
        "time" : NumberLong(1541158908),
    },
    {
        "_id" : 4,
        "booking_id" : 95,
        "provider_id" : 20,
        "type" : "abc",
        "time" : NumberLong(1541163544),
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 30.711858,
            "lng" : 76.729649
        },
    },
    {
        "_id" : 8,
        "booking_id" : 95,
        "provider_id" : 20,
        "type" : "aaa",
    }
]
```

I have to  group data of similar booking_id, Now how can I get a data of simlilar booking id using $group aggregation.I want a data in a following structure::

```
result: [
    0:[
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "booking_id" : 96,
            "provider_id" : 20,
            "time" : NumberLong(1541158790),
            "arrival_time" : NumberLong(1541158863)
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "booking_id" : 96,
            "provider_id" : 20,
            "time" : NumberLong(1541158908),
        },
    ],
    1:[
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "booking_id" : 95,
            "provider_id" : 20,
            "type" : "abc",
            "time" : NumberLong(1541163544),
            "location" : {
                "lat" : 30.711858,
                "lng" : 76.729649
            },
        },
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "booking_id" : 95,
            "provider_id" : 20,
            "type" : "aaa",
        }
    ]
]
```

I have created a function which is returing result of this collection and using $group like this:

```
query := []bson.M{
        {"$group": bson.M{
            "_id": bson.M{"booking_id": "$booking_id"},
            "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1}}}}
pipe := getCollection.Pipe(query)
err = pipe.All(&result)
```

But it will return this output to me:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "booking_id": 0,
        "provider_id": 0
    }
]
```

Here I am mentioning only two booking ids data, I have 1000 of booking id records in my database.
I want to show data grouped by booking id, Is it possible using mongodb $group aggregation?? Or if not then how can I achieve this thing in mongodb using mgo package for golang.

Comment: What have you actually tried? It is very possible, if not in the way you are demonstrating exactly as expected output since that expected output format is actually invalid. The `$push` operator can be used to create arrays of data related to a specific grouping key, and there are plenty of [examples out there on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+aggregate+%24push+example). Asking "questions" here about making changes to attempted code is fine. But outright "Please write my code for me!" questions are strongly discouraged, and their closure is well warranted. Show some attempt.

Comment: I also mentioned function query which I am using to return grouped output. But it returns no values. Can you please check why this is happening

Comment: The strange thing is that your result does not seem to come from the grouping operation as it has different attributes. How do you exactly print the output?

Comment: In output it is showing a result  attribute which are mentioned inside response struct. And here result is of type response struct. But why it is not showing output from grouping operation?

Comment: Here result is of type response having all the fields mentioned above.{pipe.All(&result)} if I am getting all the result of response it is fine for me. But I want a result to be grouped by booking_id. For this I am using $group aggregation. But it seems like there is some issue with it, because it gives no output to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use $group and [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT), which references the document currently being processed in the pipeline. 
Your aggregation would be something like:

```
{ 
    $group: {
      _id: '$booking_id',
      items: {
        $push: '$$ROOT'
      }
    }
}
```

Which would result in this:

```
 [
    {
        "_id": 95,
        "items": [
           {
            "_id" : 1,
            "booking_id" : 96,
            "provider_id" : 20,
            "time" : NumberLong(1541158790),
            "arrival_time" : NumberLong(1541158863)
          },
          {
            "_id" : 3,
            "booking_id" : 96,
            "provider_id" : 20,
            "time" : NumberLong(1541158908),
          },
        ]
   }
],
...
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to show both `booking_id` and `provider_id`, you can group by these both fields and project the data the way you want. Like this:

```
[
{
    $group: {
        _id: { 'booking_id': '$booking_id', 'provider_id': '$provider_id' },
        items: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        booking_id: '$_id.booking_id',
        provider_id: '$_id.provider_id',
        items: 1 
    }
}
]
```

Giving this structure:

```
[
{
    "booking_id": 96,
    "provider_id": 20,
    "items": [
       {
        "_id" : 1,
        "booking_id" : 96,
        "provider_id" : 20,
        "time" : NumberLong(1541158790),
        "arrival_time" : NumberLong(1541158863)
      },
      {
        "_id" : 3,
        "booking_id" : 96,
        "provider_id" : 20,
        "time" : NumberLong(1541158908),
      },
    ]
 }
],
...
```

Comment: If I am using $group and $$ROOT together , it gives same result for me, but I also want provider_id outside the items array.
{   "_id": 95, "provider_id":20, "items": [ ] }    Is it possible when I am using $$ROOT, because I am using $push accumulator to push provider_id before $$ROOT, but it includes provider_id inside "items"